# Heating problem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, overheating

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Intel Core-I7 machine and it heats up terribly. On the other hand, Windows 7 on the same machine works pretty fine.

Are there any fixes or suggestions on how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Same happens with my pc too

Comment: @enjo - Yes, the system heats even when it is idle.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying thermald, this will actively monitor hot thermal zones and will try various methods to try and cool a machine.

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

For more details, consult the kernel team [thermald][1] reference guide.